# How do I get my transaction Id to sign the transaction?

Tags: cleos, eosjs, eosio-code

While signing the transaction there are 3 parameters that we need to pass, 
1) txn
2) keys
3) id

How Can I get my id and also what should be the structure of the transaction parameter, Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signing a transaction requires the Transaction, the Keys to Sign with, and the *Chain ID*.  The Chain ID can be obtained via the `get_info` call against the chain.